# If statement on timer is not working

Tags: actionscript, if-statement, timer

I'm having trouble with an `if` statement I've created. Can't see why it's not working so was hoping some fresh eyes might help!

I have a timer:

```
var delayTimer:Timer = new Timer(9000,1);
```

And a function on another frame

```
delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timesUp);
function timesUp(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
   if (delayTimer.currentCount == 9)
   {
      trace.("which it does")
      incorrect.stop();
      timesup.play();
   }
   else
   {
      incorrect.play();
      timesup.stop();
   }
}
```

My tracer doesn't seem to increment so obviously something is going wrong with my function. `incorrect` and `timesup` are both movie clips that I need to play when the timer = 9. So if the timer runs out, it will play movie clip `times up` and not `incorrect`.

I've got a few other if else statements that use the same structure but work, so I'm slightly perplexed by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Timer.currentCount`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#currentCount) is *“[t]he total number of times the timer has fired since it started at zero”*. As you specified in the constructor, that the timer repeats a single time, `currentCount` will never reach the count of 9.

What you probably want to do is to simply trigger when the timer actually runs out, i.e. after the delay of 9000 milliseconds. This is exactly what the `TIMER` event does. It will fire when the delay is over and the timer fires. The event will fire once in your case, as you specified the timer to run only once (it will fire once with `currentCount` being `0`). The `TIMER_COMPLETE` event will fire once at the end, after all repetitions are over, in your case, directly after the `TIMER` event was fired.

In response to your comment, here is how I’d do it (and how I understood what you are trying to do):

```
var delayTimer:Timer = new Timer(9000, 1);
delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timesUp);

function timesUp (evt:TimerEvent):void
{
    // after the timeout
    incorrect.stop();
    timesup.play();
}

// start the timer
delayTimer.start();

// start the animation, that occurs while the timer runs
incorrect.play();
timesup.stop();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me! Are you basically saying to remove the 'if' statement?

Comment: Basically, yes. The event only fires when the timer actually runs out, so I guess what you want to do in the `== 9` case is what you actually want to do in the event handler, and what you want to do in the else case is what you want to do outside of it, just when you start the timer.

Comment: Sorry bout this but I'm relatively new to flash, so while I understand what you're saying, I'm not 100% sure how to implement it. Not asking for you to feed me to the code, you've been helpful so far, but any chance of an example?